# How can I call the wcf service method?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a method like this in wcf service

```
public string PostAllSurveList(List<Survey> surveyList)
        {
            var surveyDbList = ConstructDbServeyList(surveyList);
            foreach (var survey in surveyDbList)
            {
                _db.surveys.Add(survey);
            }
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return "Successfully Saved";
        }
```

Now my question is How can I call this method from the client code. That means firstly I have to construct the Survey List. How can I construct this list.

```
string reply = client.PostAllSurveList(How can I construct this List?);
```

For your kind information, I am writing client code in C#.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Create object of args list and supply that

Comment: well, you need to contruct a survey list of type survey like this ` List<survey>` and pass it to your method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var list = new List<Survey>();    
string reply = client.PostAllSurveList(list);
```

And you *really* need to make sure you know how to spell Survey, because you have 3 different spellings in 6 lines of code. Code is *written* language, it doesn't work if it's somewhat similar if spoken aloud.

**Edit:**
Make sure that when you generate the client, you chose "List" as the option for any collections. It seems you chose array, which means your function now takes an array on the client side:

```
var list = new List<Survey>();    
string reply = client.PostAllSurveList(list.ToArray());
```

Comment: what are the different spelling have you found?? I just copied from my written code. I got my error in your edited portion. But there is no error in the 6 lines of code. Think before being rude. any way your answer is right. thanks

Comment: Your 3 different spellings of "Survey" in above code are: Servey, Survey and Surve. If you use a tool like Visual Studio Code Analysis, it will give warnings for spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Create survery items and add them to a list, pass the list as parameter:

```
Survey survey1 = new Survey();

survey1.property1= value;
survey1.property2= value;

Survey survey2 = new Survey();

survey2.property1= value;
survey2.property2= value;

List<Survey> listSurvey = new List<Survey>();
listSurvey.add(survey1);
listSurvey.add(survey2);

string reply = client.PostAllSurveList(listSurvey);
```

Comment: The properties are examples!!! I do not know the properties of your survey class. You did not paste them

Answer (score 1):

**Creare List like this and supply :**

```
var list = new List<Survey>();
string reply = client.PostAllSurveList(list);
```

Edit :
Update Service Reference To ObservableCollection
[image]

Comment: Everyone here is trying to help you out and you're just complaining about compile errors...

Comment: Given in the @ Darren Davies's answer

Comment: Update Service Reference And Make it to Convert GenaricList

Comment: No Need To Convert In Array

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var list = new List<Survey>();
string reply = client.PostAllSurveList(list);
```

Or using an `Collection Initializer`:

```
string reply = client.PostAllSurveList(new List<Survey> { });
```

Although `list` should be populated elsewhere in your business logic, unless `ConstructDbServeyList` manipulates the variable in the method directly.

You can add to the list using the `.Add()` method.  For instance:

```
list.Add(new Survey() { Property = "Property"; });
```

Comment: in this line i am getting compile time error 
string reply = client.PostAllSurveList(new List<Survey> { });

Comment: @AtishDipongkor - what is the error? Did you try `var list = new List<Survey>(); string reply = client.PostAllSurveList(list); `

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'ConsumeSurveyService.SurveyService.DataGetPostService.PostAllSurveList(ConsumeSurveyService.SurveyService.Survey[])' has some invalid arguments F:\BS_Intern\Suvey Web Service\Servey\ConsumeSurveyService\Program.cs 20 28 ConsumeSurveyService